# Data frame in R with vectors containing other vectors

Tags: r

I have some vectors of different sizes in R, let's say:

```
A<-c(A1,A2,A3)
B<-c(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5)
C<-c(C1,C2)
```

And i join them into a list:

```
V1<-c(list(A,B,C))
```

Now i have another set of vectors, again of different sizes:

```
D<-c(D1,D2,D3,D4)
E<-c(E1,E2)
F<-c(F1,F2,F3,F4,F5)
```

And again i join them into another list:

```
V2<-c(list(D,E,F))
```

A1, A2, B1, B2, etc. are numbers.

Now, i try to make a data frame using those two vectors V1 and V2:

```
df<-data.frame(V1,V2)
```

..but i got an error: "arguments imply differing number of rows".

My question is, It's possible to make a data frame like this one? And if it's possible, How?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: To create a data frame with lists as columns, you can wrap the lists with `I`. `data.frame(V1 = I(V1), V2 = I(V2))`

Comment: Psidom answer was EXACTLY what was lacking in my code, thanks a lot!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Psidom got the answer:

To create a data frame with lists as columns, you can wrap the lists with I. data.frame(V1 = I(V1), V2 = I(V2)).

I cannot accept the comment as the answer, but this is it.

Thanks to Psidom!

Answer (score 0):

The `data_frame` from `dplyr` can directly take a `list` column

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame(V1, V2)
# A tibble: 3 × 2
#        V1        V2
#     <list>    <list>
#1 <chr [3]> <chr [4]>
#2 <chr [5]> <chr [2]>
#3 <chr [2]> <chr [5]>
```

Comment: It gives me the same error (arguments imply differing number of rows). But Psidom comment worked for me!

Comment: @Ghost I am not sure whether you have an different version of `dplyr`.  I am using `dplyr_0.5.0`

Comment: akrun, don't worry, the issue is already solved; Psidom got the answer, is just that i don't know how to accept a comment as the answer.